# How to make mscharts y axis always go to a specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

For reasons I cannot fathom, a client wants the chart to always go to 1000. Regardless of whether the maximum data point is 300 or something and usually goes nowhere near 1000, they want to see the axis go to 1000. I tried using

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].YAxis.Maximum = 1000;
```

But that doesn't do anything, presumably because it only comes into play if you have a value over 100 (which is logical). Is there anyway to force the y axis to go to a certain value even if *sigh* the data never goes anywhere near that high? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I'm dumb I was pointing to an older version that wasn't using the Maximum property. That property does exactly what I need.